# Making a UIImageView appear when screen is tapped

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview, tap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making images appear… How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970293/making-images-appear-how)

Hi all, Could someone please tell me how to make an image appear when the user taps the screen and make it appear at the position of the tap. Thanks in advance, Tate